# Как получить координаты нажатия на карту?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Как получить координаты нажатия на карту? Чтобы позже использовать для установки маркера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package com.example.sfp.googlemaps

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions

class MapsActivity : FragmentActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private var mMap: GoogleMap? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)

        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }


    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap


    mMap!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(55.7877134, 37.5433791), 12f))
 mMap!!.setOnMapClickListener(object: GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener {
                override fun onMapClick(latLng:LatLng) {
                    var myPos = latLng
                    val secPos = myPos
                    mMap!!.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(myPos)).setVisible(true)
                    if (myPos != secPos){
                        mMap!!.mar
                    }    
            })        
        }    
    }
```

Comment: это пример на Kotlin?

Comment: Да, это Kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

            // Creating a marker
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting the position for the marker
            markerOptions.position(latLng);

            // Setting the title for the marker.
            // This will be displayed on taping the marker
            markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude + " : " + latLng.longitude);

            // Clears the previously touched position
            googleMap.clear();

            // Animating to the touched position
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

            // Placing a marker on the touched position
            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }
    });
```